# How to filter case insensitive my OData in a UI5 app?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to filter a data set with a searchField, but when building the filter, there is no documented way to filter case-insensitive. Could you help me?

This is how I build my filter:

```
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery);
```

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom filter by manually providing the filter function ([docu](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter/constructor))

```
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    path: "name",
    test: function(sValue) {
        return sValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(sQuery.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the OData tolower() function to compare to lower-case strings.

```
var oFilter = new Filter("tolower(name)",
     FilterOperator.Contains,"'" + sQuery.toLowerCase().replace("'","''") + "'");
```

sap.ui.model.Filter and sap.ui.model.FilterOperator must be referenced.

[Case insensitive filter explained](https://w3ka.blogspot.com/2018/09/case-insensitive-filtering-of-odata.html)